# Eigen extracting submatrix from vector of indices

Tags: c++, eigen

I have been googling for a while now, but cant find the answer to this simple question.

In matlab i can do this:

```
rows = [1 3 5 9];
A = rand(10);
B = A(rows, : );
```

How do i do this in eigen? It does not seem like it is possible. The closest thing i have found is

```
MatrixXd a(10,10);
a.row(1);
```

,but I want to get multiple rows/cols. Another user has also asked the question here: [How to extract a subvector (of a Eigen::Vector) from a vector of indices in Eigen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26267194/how-to-extract-a-subvector-of-a-eigenvector-from-a-vector-of-indices-in-eige) , but I think there must some built in way of doing this because it is a really common operation I think.

Thanks.

Comment: For anyone who stumbles on to this page years later (like myself)... I just wanted to add to @chtz's answer  that Gael responded to the feature request last year. The feature is currently available in Eigen's dev branch. 
See this link for documentation:

http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#a0b44220621cd59a75cd0f48cc499518f -  posted on behalf of https://stackoverflow.com/users/3077484/alice-schwarze request.

Comment: Maybe not precisely what you're looking for, but the [Eigen `block` operations](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialBlockOperations.html) are useful for getting subsets of Eigen matrices.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While this was not possible at the time this question was asked, it has since been added in the development branch!

It's very straight forward:

```
Eigen::MatrixXf matrix;
Eigen::VectorXi columns;
Eigen::MatrixXf extracted_cols = matrix(Eigen::all, columns);
```

So I'm guessing this will be in the <s>3.3.5</s> 3.4 stable release. Until then the development branch is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is still not directly supported even in Eigen 3.3. There has been this feature request for a while:
http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=329

Gael linked to an example implementation in one of the comments there:
http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicCustomizing_NullaryExpr.html#title1

Answer (score -1):

Ok, say for example you have a 3x3 matrix:

```
m = [3   -1   1; 2.5  1.5 6; 4    7   1]
```

and say you want to extract following rows from m matrix:

```
[0 2], // row 0 and row 2
```

essentially giving out following matrix:

```
new_extracted_matrix = [3 -1 1; 4  7 1]  // row 0 and row 2 of matrix m
```

Main thing here is, let's create a vector v having contents [0 2], means we would extract following row indices from matrix m.
Here is what i did:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  Matrix3f m;
  m(0,0) = 3;
  m(0,1) = -1;
  m(0,2) = 1;  
  m(1,0) = 2.5;
  m(1,1) = m(1,0) + m(0,1);
  m(1,2) = 6;
  m(2,0) = 4;
  m(2,1) = 7;
  m(2,2) = 1;  
  std::cout << "Here is the matrix m:\n" << m << std::endl; // Creating a random 3x3 matrix
  VectorXf v(2);
  v(0) = 0; // Extracting row 0
  v(1) = 2; // Extracting row 2

  MatrixXf r(1,v.size());
  for (int i=0;i<v.size();i++)
  {
      r.col(i) << v(i); // Creating indice vector
  }
  cout << "The extracted row indicies of above matrix: " << endl << r << endl;

  MatrixXf N = MatrixXf::Zero(r.size(),m.cols());
  for (int z=0;z<r.size();z++)
  {
    N.row(z) = m.row(r(z));
  }

  cout << "Extracted rows of given matrix: " << endl << N << endl;
}
```

This would give us following output:

> Here is the matrix m:
> [3  -1   1;  2.5 1.5   6; 4   7   1]
>
> The extracted row indicies of above matrix:
> [0 2]
>
> Extracted rows of given matrix:
> [3 -1  1; 4  7  1]